# Error 401 Unauthorized in Docuware ServiceConnection.Create

Tags: c#

I'm using in a C# projet where we're using the Docuware API for electronic document management.

Sometimes, when i'm doing some unit test, I have an HttpClientRequestException - 401 Unauthorized (not every time) and I don't understand why.. Why does it happen only some time..

This is my connection code :

```
Uri uri = new Uri(adresse);
this.ServiceConnection = ServiceConnection.Create(uri, username, password);
```

this exception is thrown during the Create.

Does someone already face this problem and I hope solved it?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Did you check if there were licenses available? If you're running 6.9 now, you can check the used licenses in the DocuWare Administration (Windows application).

Comment: If you don't keep the .DWPLATFORMAUTH-Cookie(s) after a successful request, you end up using a license for each call. I assume that the .Net library provided by DocuWare itself will be aware of this, but if you are developing your own client, you should keep the cookie and put in your request headers.

Answer (score 0):

a quick look in the platform log might reveal the real error - http://your_server/DocuWare/Platform/Home/LogMessages

Error handling will be improved, so that you get a reasonable exception.